# images don't render in browser

Tags: html, css, gulp, gulp-sass

I use gulp as a automation and build system and when I build websites when i have background image in my css file added as a background-image property when I run gulp everything render properly in the browser, when I try to open index.html with gulp off images which comes from css files aren't rendered only those ones which are embedded with img tag in my html file works fine it happens even with build version of my website.

my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var htmlMin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var del = require('del');
var sequence = require('run-sequence');


// Server
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: 'src'
    });

    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Compile SASS to CSS
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
               .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
               .pipe(autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 3 versions']
               }))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
               .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

});

gulp.task('img', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}')
        .pipe(changed('dist/img'))
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));

});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlReplace({
            'css': 'css/main.css',
            'js': 'js/script.js'
        }))
        .pipe(htmlMin({
            sortAttributes: true,
            sortClassName: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(['dist'])
});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    sequence('clean', ['html', 'js', 'css', 'img']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.6.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-changed": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.10.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.2",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
}
```